# How to scrape encoded with base 64 image and store in database using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am Trying to **scrape** images frm websites but that are encoded with the base 64. so how can i do it using python, beautifulsoup.

I tried the code using python urllib , but it is not going to work.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import base64
import os
from string import ascii_lowercase

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata
soup = make_soup("https://mahabhunakasha.mahabhumi.gov.in/bhunaksha/27/index.jsp")
soups = soup.decode('utf-8')

print(soups)
# for img in soup.findAll("src"):
#     print(img)
```

I want to download that all images from all areas and store in mongo database.

Comment: what does the error say? is it `SSLCertVerificationError`?

Comment: @ ans2human :- yes. urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>

Comment: FYI It’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the SSL error I used selenium, you can download a firefox [exe](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and pass the executable path, then you will be able to scrape the page  once you install the selenium module with the following:

```
#!pip install selenium

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\Gecko\geckodriver.exe')
thepage = driver.get("https://mahabhunakasha.mahabhumi.gov.in/bhunaksha/27/index.jsp")
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
```

I did not see any images on this page, it seems to be a canvas class.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i directly bypass it by monkey patch `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`